# ODBC VB Throwing syntax error

Tags: vb.net, syntax, odbc

I cant see what is wrong with my SQL statement syntax code is here:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using Con1 As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=MyGame;User=root; Password=MyPasswordWhichIWontTellYou;")
        Dim mInsertSQL As String
        mInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts (Username,Password,Str,Int,Agi,Money) VALUES ('" & txtUser.Text & "','" & txtPass.Text & "'," & Int(txtStr.Text) & "," & Int(txtInt.Text) & "," & Int(txtAgi.Text) & ",0);"
        Dim Cmd1 As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(mInsertSQL, Con1)
        Try
            Con1.Open()
            Cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Just for clarity the actual insert statement is this with some data:

```
"INSERT INTO Accounts (Username,Password,Str,Int,Agi,Money) VALUES ('MyUsername','MyPassword',0,0,0,0)"
```

The error given is:

```
ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.41]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Int,Agi,Money) VALUES ('MyUsername','MyPassword',0,0,0,0)' at line 1
```

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild Guess: 'Int' as a field name may be reserved, maybe you could try another name for the field?

Comment: Or if you cannot try to replace Int by "Int".